# VBA Function able to search through cells?

Tags: vba, excel

#### Back Story

At my job we use a desk calendar to keep track of a multitude of random details that occur: Everyone's daily hours, what type and how many reports were sent, etc. To help us in filling out a few forms my boss decided he wanted to create a spreadsheet for the month and keep it as up-to-date as possible day by day. He went on vacation before this month started, so I've been taking over his duties. Something I noticed is that he hardwired the calculations for the totals (everyone's total hours, total reports sent, etc), so that when I changed the dates from January to February we had some left over ones that lead into March. I deleted them and then the formulas all threw #REF! errors because of it.

How the data is set up is simple:

```
AB    2.50
CD    3.50
EF    8.00
...ETC...
```

With the AB,CD,EF being in one column, and the values being in the adjacent column.

#### The Question

I tried to get this to work, with no luck, so I'm thinking it might be impossible but I thought I'd ask a group of people who know more about the subject than I do: in a function I made I have it accept a string parameter to search for, if it finds it, it moves to the adjacent cell and adds that value to the running total. It then returns that number at the end, so a call to this function would resemble

```
=getTotals("AB")  ' this would display whatever the total for AB is
```

But when I tried this all I got was a #VALUE! error in the cell.

Is there any way I can get this to work the way I want it to, without the use of a full macro?

#### The Function

I got this function to work, how I wanted to

```
Function getTotal(rng As Range, search As String) As Double

    Dim r As Range

    getTotal = 0

    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value = search Then
            getTotal = getTotal + r.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Calling it like so: =getTotal(A1:D2, "AD")

Comment: Excel UDFS cannot change worksheet cells...

Comment: @Jhecht, can you post your function logic?

Comment: Not currently, it basically used the cells.find() method to search through the sheet and total everything. When I can I'll post it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SUMIF` should get you what you need:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,"AB",B1:B10)
```

Assuming your 'AB' values are in column A, rows 1-10 and the number values are in column B, rows 1-10.

The first argument in `SUMIF` is the range to check, the second argument is the condition that must be met (search criteria), and the 3rd [optional] argument is the corresponding range from which to get the values to be summed.

Comment: + 1 Spot On! :) Or even Sumproduct

Comment: `SUMIFS` if you have more than 1 search criteria.

Comment: I think this might be what I was looking for. I feel very silly because I knew this function existed. I'll let you know.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it is what gave me the idea